# django retrieving all objects from one to many model relationship in shell

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many, django-shell

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 
# Create your models here.
 
class Board(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
 
class Task(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        done = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        board = models.ForeignKey(Board, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
 
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
```

how can I get all tasks that are inside one board? (every user can create a board and inside that board the user can create tasks) I've tried `Board.objects.get(pk=1).title.title` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please share *code* not images of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the `Board` object, and then query with `task_set`:

```
board = Board.objects.get(pk=1)
board.task_set.all()  # queryset of related Tasks
```

If you are not interested in the `Board` itself, you can omit querying the `Board`, and filter with:

```
Task.objects.filter(board_id=1)  # queryset of related Tasks
```